# When to start tarpanam

Tags: rituals

My Maternal Uncle (mother`s elder brother) passed away 4 days ago. His wife passed away 24 years ago. All this while my Maternal Uncle was performing Tila Tarpanam for his wife. My question is can my cousin perform Amavasya Tarpanam, Mahalaya Tarpanam for my Aunt during this 1 year? Will he be eligible to perform Tarpanam of His mother only after the completion of Prathyabdika of his father or he can start performing Tila Tarpanam next Amavasya itself?

Comment: Personal advice questions are off-topic. Please make the question objective removing personal details.

Answer (score 3):

There are many types of tarpanam like deva tarpanam and rishi tarpanam etc. But since you are specific about pitru tarpanam then the main ones to perform are monthly amavasya tarpanam and yearly tarpanam in mahAlaya paksha before navaratri.

If there is no one to perform tarpanam for the deceased then relatives can do it.

You can get some basic info [here](http://samskaaram.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=31:pitrutarpanam&catid=111&Itemid=603&lang=en) and there are many websites and YouTube videos to get idea how is it done.